# Xades countersign document

Tags: xades4j

I have an XML document which is already Xades signed. Now I want to counter sign this signature. How can I do this with Xades4j? I have searched the documentation but there is only example how to sign and countersign together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [format extender](http://code.google.com/p/xades4j/wiki/SignatureEnrichment#Creating_an_Extender) directly to [add new unsigned properties](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/production/XadesSignatureFormatExtender.html) to an existing signature.

Comment: Greate job. It really helped me a lot.