# xades4j how to add countersign

Tags: xml, digital-signature, xades4j

This is my code to sign XML document:

```
KeyingDataProvider kp = new FileSystemKeyStoreKeyingDataProvider(keyStoreType, 
    keyStorePath, certificateSelector, keyStorePasswordProvider, 
    entryPasswordProvider, returnFullChain);
XadesSigningProfile p = new XadesBesSigningProfile(kp);

XadesSigner signer = p.newSigner();

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();     

docSource = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(pathToXmlFile));
docDest = builder.newDocument();

Node objContent = docDest.importNode(docSource.getDocumentElement(), true);

DataObjectDesc obj = new EnvelopedXmlObject(objContent, "text/xml", null);

new Enveloped(signer).sign(docSource.getDocumentElement());
```

Now, to the same XML file I need to add counter signature. Could you please give me some advices on how to do it? At the moment I don't have any ideas :(

My XML file looks like this:

```
<rootElement>
  <A>
    <A1>
    </A1>
  </A>
</rootElement>
```

After first signature I have:

```
<rootElement>
  <A>
    <A1>
    </A1>
  </A>
  <ds:Signature>
  </ds:Signature>
</rootElement>
```

Best regards
John S.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this test](https://code.google.com/p/xades4j/source/browse/src/test/java/xades4j/production/SignerBESTest.java#82) on the library source code. It generates a signature that contains a counter signature. Basically, you need to define a `SignaturePropertiesProvider` that adds the `CounterSignature` property and add it to your signing profile. Note that the `CounterSignatureProperty` receives another signer, used to generate the counter signature.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the provided sample is showing how to countersign a document together with regular signing. I already have signed XML and I want to extend it with countersignature. I found this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696429/xades-countersign-document but it doesn't really explain me how to achieve that. I now it might be a stupid question, but I'm begginer in JAVA and have no clue how to make it working.

Comment: You can try using a XadesSignatureFormatExtender directly - https://code.google.com/p/xades4j/wiki/SignatureEnrichment